# App taking too much memory when using Google Map V2 in Android

Tags: android, android-maps-v2

I am using the Google Map V2 and draw the route between two locations and internet connectivity (calling only webservice) and no background service and thread and receiver.

But Still its taking too much memory. Please see the attached picture. Is there any way to reduce it.

```
public class LocationMapFragment extends FragmentActivity {


    private ArrayList<LatLng> latLongArrayList = new ArrayList<LatLng>();

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        this.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        setContentView(R.layout.map_layout);

        context = this;

        Location location = Utils.getGPSLocation(context);
        if(location != null) {
            currentLatitude = location.getLatitude();
            currentLongitude = location.getLongitude();
            setLayout();
        }

    }


    public void setLayout() {
        display = this.getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();

        map = ((SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map)).getMap();
        map.setMyLocationEnabled(true);

        if(getIntent().getBooleanExtra("isFromSameActivity", false)) {
            // Getting reference to SupportMapFragment of the activity_main
            map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(currentLatitude, currentLongitude)).title("You are Here"));

            latitude = getIntent().getDoubleExtra("selectLatitude", 0);
            longitude = getIntent().getDoubleExtra("selectLongitude", 0);

            latLongArrayList.add(new LatLng(latitude, longitude));

            if(searchLatitude != 0 && searchLongitude != 0) {
                new SearchGetNearestATM().execute();
                latLongArrayList.add(new LatLng(searchLatitude, searchLongitude));
            } else {
                new GetNearestATM().execute();
                if(currentLatitude != 0 && currentLongitude != 0)
                    latLongArrayList.add(new LatLng(currentLatitude, currentLongitude));
            }
        }
        else if(!getIntent().getBooleanExtra("isAtmClick", false)) {
            // Getting reference to SupportMapFragment of the activity_main
            map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(currentLatitude, currentLongitude)).title("You are Here"));
            if(searchLatitude != 0 && searchLongitude != 0) {
                new SearchGetNearestATM().execute();
                latLongArrayList.add(new LatLng(searchLatitude, searchLongitude));
            } else {
                new GetNearestATM().execute();
                if(currentLatitude != 0 && currentLongitude != 0)
                    latLongArrayList.add(new LatLng(currentLatitude, currentLongitude));
            }
        }
        else {
            isATMCLick = true;
            latitude = getIntent().getDoubleExtra("selectLatitude", 0);
            longitude = getIntent().getDoubleExtra("selectLongitude", 0);

            if(searchLatitude != 0 && searchLongitude != 0)
                latLongArrayList.add(new LatLng(searchLatitude, searchLongitude));
            else {
                if(currentLatitude != 0 && currentLongitude != 0)
                    latLongArrayList.add(new LatLng(currentLongitude, currentLongitude));
            }
            map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(currentLatitude, currentLongitude)).title("You are Here"));

            double latitudeArray[] = getIntent().getDoubleArrayExtra("latitude");
            double longitudeArray[] = getIntent().getDoubleArrayExtra("longitude");
            String namesArray[] = getIntent().getStringArrayExtra("names");
            String typeArray[] = getIntent().getStringArrayExtra("typeList");

            for(int index = 0; index < latitudeArray.length; index++) {
                latLongArrayList.add(new LatLng(latitudeArray[index], longitudeArray[index]));
                if(!getIntent().getStringExtra("selectName").equals(namesArray[index])) {

                    if(typeArray[index].equals("1")) {
                        map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(
                                latitudeArray[index], longitudeArray[index])).title(namesArray[index] + "\nClick to Get Directions")
                                .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.first)));
                    } else if(typeArray[index].equals("2")) {
                        map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(
                                latitudeArray[index], longitudeArray[index])).title(namesArray[index] + "\nClick to Get Directions")
                                .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.second)));
                    } else if(typeArray[index].equals("3")) {
                        map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(
                                latitudeArray[index], longitudeArray[index])).title(namesArray[index] + "\nClick to Get Directions")
                                .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.third)));
                    } else if(typeArray[index].equals("4")) {
                        map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(
                                latitudeArray[index], longitudeArray[index])).title(namesArray[index] + "\nClick to Get Directions")
                                .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.fourth)));
                    } else if(typeArray[index].equals("5")) {
                        map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(
                                latitudeArray[index], longitudeArray[index])).title(namesArray[index] + "\nClick to Get Directions")
                                .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.fifth)));
                    } else if(typeArray[index].equals("6")) {
                        map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(
                                latitudeArray[index], longitudeArray[index])).title(namesArray[index] + "\nClick to Get Directions")
                                .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.sixth)));
                    } else if(typeArray[index].equals("7")) {
                        map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(
                                latitudeArray[index], longitudeArray[index])).title(namesArray[index] + "\nClick to Get Directions")
                                .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.seventh)));
                    } else if(typeArray[index].equals("8")) {
                        map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(
                                latitudeArray[index], longitudeArray[index])).title(namesArray[index] + "\nClick to Get Directions")
                                .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.eight)));
                    } else if(typeArray[index].equals("9")) {
                        map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(
                                latitudeArray[index], longitudeArray[index])).title(namesArray[index] + "\nClick to Get Directions")
                                .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.ninth)));
                    }
                }
                else {
                    if(typeArray[index].equals("1")) {
                        map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(
                                latitudeArray[index], longitudeArray[index])).title(namesArray[index] + "\nClick to Get Directions")
                                .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.first)));
                    } else if(typeArray[index].equals("2")) {
                        map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(
                                latitudeArray[index], longitudeArray[index])).title(namesArray[index] + "\nClick to Get Directions")
                                .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.second)));
                    } else if(typeArray[index].equals("3")) {
                        map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(
                                latitudeArray[index], longitudeArray[index])).title(namesArray[index] + "\nClick to Get Directions")
                                .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.third)));
                    } else if(typeArray[index].equals("4")) {
                        map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(
                                latitudeArray[index], longitudeArray[index])).title(namesArray[index] + "\nClick to Get Directions")
                                .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.fourth)));
                    } else if(typeArray[index].equals("5")) {
                        map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(
                                latitudeArray[index], longitudeArray[index])).title(namesArray[index] + "\nClick to Get Directions")
                                .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.fifth)));
                    } else if(typeArray[index].equals("6")) {
                        map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(
                                latitudeArray[index], longitudeArray[index])).title(namesArray[index] + "\nClick to Get Directions")
                                .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.sixth)));
                    } else if(typeArray[index].equals("7")) {
                        map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(
                                latitudeArray[index], longitudeArray[index])).title(namesArray[index] + "\nClick to Get Directions")
                                .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.seventh)));
                    } else if(typeArray[index].equals("8")) {
                        map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(
                                latitudeArray[index], longitudeArray[index])).title(namesArray[index] + "\nClick to Get Directions") 
                                .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.eight)));
                    } else if(typeArray[index].equals("9")) {
                        map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(
                                latitudeArray[index], longitudeArray[index])).title(namesArray[index] + "\net Directions")
                                .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.n)));
                    }

                    //Driving Direction
                    new GetDrivingDirectionsAsync().execute();

                    map.setInfoWindowAdapter(new PopupAdapter(getLayoutInflater()));
                    //Marker Click Listener
                    map.setOnInfoWindowClickListener(new OnInfoWindowClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onInfoWindowClick(Marker marker) {
                            LatLng latLng = marker.getPosition();
                            latitude = latLng.latitude;
                            longitude = latLng.longitude;
                            Intent intent = new Intent(context, AndroidTabLayoutActivity.class);
                            intent.putExtra("isFromSameActivity", true);
                            intent.putExtra("selectLatitude", latitude);
                            intent.putExtra("selectLongitude", longitude);
                            startActivity(intent);
                        }
                    });
                }
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onPrepareOptionsMenu (Menu menu) {
        if(!isATMCLick) {
            menu.removeItem(R.id.navigate);
        }
        menu.removeItem(R.id.settings);
        return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        MenuInflater inflater=getMenuInflater();
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.map_menu, menu);
        return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        switch(item.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.navigate:
                startActivity(new Intent("android.intent.action.VIEW", Uri.parse("http://maps.google.com/maps?daddr=" + latitude + "," + longitude + "&saddr=" + currentLatitude + "," + currentLongitude)));
                break;
            case R.id.settings:
                startActivity(new Intent(context, ChangeLanguageActivity.class));
                break;
        }
        return true;
    }

    /**
     * It fetch the nearest ATM on basis of latitude and longitude.
     * @author Ankit
     */
    private class GetNearestATM extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

        String xmlResponse;
        ProgressDialog progressDialog;

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            progressDialog =  new ProgressDialog(context);
            progressDialog.setTitle(getString(R.string.app_name));
            progressDialog.setMessage(getString(R.string.please_wait));
            progressDialog.setIndeterminate(true);
            progressDialog.show();
        }

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... arg0) {
            if(currentLatitude != 0 && currentLongitude != 0) {
                xmlResponse = new Utils().getXmlFromUrl("http://www.bankomaty.sk/service/?n=" + currentLatitude + "&e=" + currentLongitude +
                        "&t=" + Utils.getFilterSettings(context));
            } else {
                runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        Toast.makeText(context, getString(R.string.no_gps_fetch), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                });
            }
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
            try { 
                progressDialog.cancel();
            } catch(Exception e) { 

            }
            if(xmlResponse != null && !xmlResponse.equals("")) {
                XMLParser xmlParser = new XMLParser();
                Document document = xmlParser.getDomElement(xmlResponse);

                if(document != null) {
                    NodeList nodeList = document.getElementsByTagName("bankomaty");
                    if(nodeList.getLength() > 0) {
                        nodeList = document.getElementsByTagName("bankomat");
                        for(int index = 0; index < nodeList.getLength(); index++) {
                            try {
                                Element element = (Element) nodeList.item(index);
                                String locationCoordinates[] = xmlParser.getValue(element, "latlng").replaceAll(" ", "").split(",");
                                double latitude = Double.valueOf(locationCoordinates[0].trim()).doubleValue();
                                double longitude = Double.valueOf(locationCoordinates[1].trim()).doubleValue();

                                latLongArrayList.add(new LatLng(latitude, longitude));

                                String type = xmlParser.getValue(element, "type");

                                if(type.equals("1")) {
                                    map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(latitude, longitude)).title(new String(xmlParser.getValue(element, "name").getBytes("ISO-8859-1")) + "\nClick to Get Directions")
                                            .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.first)));
                                } else if(type.equals("2")) {
                                    map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(latitude, longitude)).title(new String(xmlParser.getValue(element, "name").getBytes("ISO-8859-1")) + "\nClick to Get Directions")
                                            .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.second)));
                                } else if(type.equals("3")) {
                                    map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(latitude, longitude)).title(new String(xmlParser.getValue(element, "name").getBytes("ISO-8859-1")) + "\nClick to Get Directions")
                                            .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.third)));
                                } else if(type.equals("4")) {
                                    map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(latitude, longitude)).title(new String(xmlParser.getValue(element, "name").getBytes("ISO-8859-1")) + "\nClick to Get Directions")
                                            .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.fourth)));
                                } else if(type.equals("5")) {
                                    map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(latitude, longitude)).title(new String(xmlParser.getValue(element, "name").getBytes("ISO-8859-1")) + "\nClick to Get Directions")
                                            .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.fifth)));
                                } else if(type.equals("6")) {
                                    map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(latitude, longitude)).title(new String(xmlParser.getValue(element, "name").getBytes("ISO-8859-1")) + "\nClick to Get Directions")
                                            .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.sixth)));
                                } else if(type.equals("7")) {
                                    map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(latitude, longitude)).title(new String(xmlParser.getValue(element, "name").getBytes("ISO-8859-1")) + "\nClick to Get Directions")
                                            .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.seventh)));
                                } else if(type.equals("8")) {
                                    map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(latitude, longitude)).title(new String(xmlParser.getValue(element, "name").getBytes("ISO-8859-1")) + "\nClick to Get Directions")
                                            .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.eight)));
                                } else if(type.equals("9")) {
                                    map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(latitude, longitude)).title(new String(xmlParser.getValue(element, "name").getBytes("ISO-8859-1")) + "\nClick to Get Directions")
                                            .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.ninth)));
                                }
                            } catch(Exception e) {
                                //Exception
                            }
                        }

                        if(!getIntent().getBooleanExtra("isFromSameActivity", false))
                            setCameraAnimation(map);

                        if(getIntent().getBooleanExtra("isFromSameActivity", false))
                            new GetDrivingDirectionsAsync().execute();

                        map.setInfoWindowAdapter(new PopupAdapter(getLayoutInflater()));
                        //Marker Click Listener
                        map.setOnInfoWindowClickListener(new OnInfoWindowClickListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onInfoWindowClick(Marker marker) {
                                LatLng latLng = marker.getPosition();
                                latitude = latLng.latitude;
                                longitude = latLng.longitude;
                                Intent intent = new Intent(context, AndroidTabLayoutActivity.class);
                                intent.putExtra("isFromSameActivity", true);
                                intent.putExtra("selectLatitude", latitude);
                                intent.putExtra("selectLongitude", longitude);
                                startActivity(intent);
                            }
                        });
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }


    /**
     * It fetch the nearest ATM on basis of latitude and longitude from seach on basis of street and city.
     * @author Ankit
     */
    private class SearchGetNearestATM extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

        String xmlResponse;
        ProgressDialog progressDialog;

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            progressDialog =  new ProgressDialog(context);
            progressDialog.setTitle(getString(R.string.app_name));
            progressDialog.setMessage(getString(R.string.please_wait));
            progressDialog.setIndeterminate(true);
            progressDialog.show();
        }

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... arg0) {
            if(LocationMapFragment.searchLatitude != 0 && LocationMapFragment.searchLongitude != 0) {
                xmlResponse = new Utils().getXmlFromUrl("http://www.bankomaty.sk/service/?n=" + LocationMapFragment.searchLatitude + "&e=" + LocationMapFragment.searchLongitude +
                        "&t=" + Utils.getFilterSettings(context));
            } else {
                runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        Toast.makeText(context, getString(R.string.no_gps_fetch), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                });
            }
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
            try { 
                progressDialog.cancel();
            } catch(Exception e) { 

            }
            if(xmlResponse != null && !xmlResponse.equals("")) {
                XMLParser xmlParser = new XMLParser();
                Document document = xmlParser.getDomElement(xmlResponse);

                if(document != null) {
                    NodeList nodeList = document.getElementsByTagName("bankomaty");
                    if(nodeList.getLength() > 0) {
                        nodeList = document.getElementsByTagName("bankomat");
                        for(int index = 0; index < nodeList.getLength(); index++) {
                            try {
                                Element element = (Element) nodeList.item(index);
                                String locationCoordinates[] = xmlParser.getValue(element, "latlng").replaceAll(" ", "").split(",");
                                double latitude = Double.valueOf(locationCoordinates[0].trim()).doubleValue();
                                double longitude = Double.valueOf(locationCoordinates[1].trim()).doubleValue();

                                latLongArrayList.add(new LatLng(latitude, longitude));

                                String type = xmlParser.getValue(element, "type");

                                if(type.equals("1")) {
                                    map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(latitude, longitude)).title(new String(xmlParser.getValue(element, "name").getBytes("ISO-8859-1")) + "\nClick to Get Directions")
                                            .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.first)));
                                } else if(type.equals("2")) {
                                    map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(latitude, longitude)).title(new String(xmlParser.getValue(element, "name").getBytes("ISO-8859-1")) + "\nClick to Get Directions")
                                            .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.second)));
                                } else if(type.equals("3")) {
                                    map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(latitude, longitude)).title(new String(xmlParser.getValue(element, "name").getBytes("ISO-8859-1")) + "\nClick to Get Directions")
                                            .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.third)));
                                } else if(type.equals("4")) {
                                    map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(latitude, longitude)).title(new String(xmlParser.getValue(element, "name").getBytes("ISO-8859-1")) + "\nClick to Get Directions")
                                            .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.fourth)));
                                } else if(type.equals("5")) {
                                    map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(latitude, longitude)).title(new String(xmlParser.getValue(element, "name").getBytes("ISO-8859-1")) + "\nClick to Get Directions")
                                            .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.fifth)));
                                } else if(type.equals("6")) {
                                    map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(latitude, longitude)).title(new String(xmlParser.getValue(element, "name").getBytes("ISO-8859-1")) + "\nClick to Get Directions")
                                            .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.sixth)));
                                } else if(type.equals("7")) {
                                    map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(latitude, longitude)).title(new String(xmlParser.getValue(element, "name").getBytes("ISO-8859-1")) + "\nClick to Get Directions")
                                            .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.seventh)));
                                } else if(type.equals("8")) {
                                    map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(latitude, longitude)).title(new String(xmlParser.getValue(element, "name").getBytes("ISO-8859-1")) + "\nClick to Get Directions")
                                            .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.eight)));
                                } else if(type.equals("9")) {
                                    map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(latitude, longitude)).title(new String(xmlParser.getValue(element, "name").getBytes("ISO-8859-1")) + "\nClick to Get Directions")
                                            .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.ninth)));
                                }
                            } catch(Exception e) {
                                //Exception
                            }
                        }

                        if(!getIntent().getBooleanExtra("isFromSameActivity", false))
                            setCameraAnimation(map);

                        if(getIntent().getBooleanExtra("isFromSameActivity", false))
                            new GetDrivingDirectionsAsync().execute();

                        map.setInfoWindowAdapter(new PopupAdapter(getLayoutInflater()));

                        //Marker Click Listener
                        map.setOnInfoWindowClickListener(new OnInfoWindowClickListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onInfoWindowClick(Marker marker) {
                                LatLng latLng = marker.getPosition();
                                latitude = latLng.latitude;
                                longitude = latLng.longitude;
                                Intent intent = new Intent(context, AndroidTabLayoutActivity.class);
                                intent.putExtra("isFromSameActivity", true);
                                intent.putExtra("selectLatitude", latitude);
                                intent.putExtra("selectLongitude", longitude);
                                intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
                                startActivity(intent);
                            }
                        });
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        super.onBackPressed();
        this.getParent().onBackPressed();
    }

    /**
     * Async Task
     */
    private class GetDrivingDirectionsAsync extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

        ProgressDialog progressDialog;
        Document document;
        GMapV2Direction md;

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            progressDialog =  new ProgressDialog(context);
            progressDialog.setTitle(getString(R.string.app_name));
            progressDialog.setMessage(getString(R.string.please_wait));
            progressDialog.setIndeterminate(true);
            progressDialog.show();
        }

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... arg0) {
            LatLng fromPosition = null;
            if(searchLatitude != 0 && searchLongitude != 0)
                fromPosition = new LatLng(searchLatitude, searchLongitude);
            else
                fromPosition = new LatLng(currentLatitude, currentLongitude);
            LatLng toPosition = new LatLng(latitude, longitude);

            md = new GMapV2Direction();
            document = md.getDocument(fromPosition, toPosition, GMapV2Direction.MODE_DRIVING);
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void param) {
            try {
                progressDialog.cancel();
            } catch(Exception e) {

            }

            try {
                ArrayList<LatLng> directionPoint = md.getDirection(document);
                latLongArrayList.addAll(directionPoint);
                setCameraAnimation(map);
                PolylineOptions rectLine = new PolylineOptions().width(4).color(Color.BLUE);

                for(int i = 0 ; i < directionPoint.size() ; i++) {          
                    rectLine.add(directionPoint.get(i));
                }
                map.addPolyline(rectLine);
            } catch(Exception e) {
                setCameraAnimation(map);
            }
        }

    }

    /**
     * Driving Directions
     * @author Ankit
     */
    private class GMapV2Direction {
        public final static String MODE_DRIVING = "driving";

        public GMapV2Direction() { }

        public Document getDocument(LatLng start, LatLng end, String mode) {
            String url = "http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/xml?" 
                    + "origin=" + start.latitude + "," + start.longitude  
                    + "&destination=" + end.latitude + "," + end.longitude 
                    + "&sensor=false&units=metric&mode=driving";

            try {
                HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
                HttpContext localContext = new BasicHttpContext();
                HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);
                HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(httpPost, localContext);
                InputStream in = response.getEntity().getContent();
                DocumentBuilder builder = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance().newDocumentBuilder();
                Document doc = builder.parse(in);
                return doc;
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return null;
        }

        public ArrayList<LatLng> getDirection (Document doc) {
            NodeList nl1, nl2, nl3;
            ArrayList<LatLng> listGeopoints = new ArrayList<LatLng>();
            nl1 = doc.getElementsByTagName("step");
            if (nl1.getLength() > 0) {
                for (int i = 0; i < nl1.getLength(); i++) {
                    Node node1 = nl1.item(i);
                    nl2 = node1.getChildNodes();

                    Node locationNode = nl2.item(getNodeIndex(nl2, "start_location"));
                    nl3 = locationNode.getChildNodes();
                    Node latNode = nl3.item(getNodeIndex(nl3, "lat"));
                    double lat = Double.parseDouble(latNode.getTextContent());
                    Node lngNode = nl3.item(getNodeIndex(nl3, "lng"));
                    double lng = Double.parseDouble(lngNode.getTextContent());
                    listGeopoints.add(new LatLng(lat, lng));

                    locationNode = nl2.item(getNodeIndex(nl2, "polyline"));
                    nl3 = locationNode.getChildNodes();
                    latNode = nl3.item(getNodeIndex(nl3, "points"));
                    ArrayList<LatLng> arr = decodePoly(latNode.getTextContent());
                    for(int j = 0 ; j < arr.size() ; j++) {
                        listGeopoints.add(new LatLng(arr.get(j).latitude, arr.get(j).longitude));
                    }

                    locationNode = nl2.item(getNodeIndex(nl2, "end_location"));
                    nl3 = locationNode.getChildNodes();
                    latNode = nl3.item(getNodeIndex(nl3, "lat"));
                    lat = Double.parseDouble(latNode.getTextContent());
                    lngNode = nl3.item(getNodeIndex(nl3, "lng"));
                    lng = Double.parseDouble(lngNode.getTextContent());
                    listGeopoints.add(new LatLng(lat, lng));
                }
            }

            return listGeopoints;
        }

        private int getNodeIndex(NodeList nl, String nodename) {
            for(int i = 0 ; i < nl.getLength() ; i++) {
                if(nl.item(i).getNodeName().equals(nodename))
                    return i;
            }
            return -1;
        }

        private ArrayList<LatLng> decodePoly(String encoded) {
            ArrayList<LatLng> poly = new ArrayList<LatLng>();
            int index = 0, len = encoded.length();
            int lat = 0, lng = 0;
            while (index < len) {
                int b, shift = 0, result = 0;
                do {
                    b = encoded.charAt(index++) - 63;
                    result |= (b & 0x1f) << shift;
                    shift += 5;
                } while (b >= 0x20);
                int dlat = ((result & 1) != 0 ? ~(result >> 1) : (result >> 1));
                lat += dlat;
                shift = 0;
                result = 0;
                do {
                    b = encoded.charAt(index++) - 63;
                    result |= (b & 0x1f) << shift;
                    shift += 5;
                } while (b >= 0x20);
                int dlng = ((result & 1) != 0 ? ~(result >> 1) : (result >> 1));
                lng += dlng;

                LatLng position = new LatLng((double) lat / 1E5, (double) lng / 1E5);
                poly.add(position);
            }
            return poly;
        }
    }

    /**
     * Auto Zoom
     * @param map
     */
    public void setCameraAnimation(GoogleMap map) {
        double[] minMaxLocationsPoints = getMinMaxLocationPoints();
        map.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngBounds(new LatLngBounds(new LatLng(minMaxLocationsPoints[0], 
                minMaxLocationsPoints[1]), new LatLng(minMaxLocationsPoints[2], minMaxLocationsPoints[3])),
                display.getWidth() , display.getHeight(), 10));
    }

    /**
     * Get the Min and Max Points
     * @return Min and Max Location Points
     */
    public double[] getMinMaxLocationPoints() {
        double[] points = new double[4];
        ArrayList<Double> latitudeArrayList = new ArrayList<Double>();
        ArrayList<Double> longitudeArrayList = new ArrayList<Double>();
        for(int index = 0; index < latLongArrayList.size(); index++) {
            LatLng latLong = latLongArrayList.get(index);
            latitudeArrayList.add(latLong.latitude);
            longitudeArrayList.add(latLong.longitude);
        }

        Double minLatitude = Collections.min(latitudeArrayList);
        Double maxLatitude = Collections.max(latitudeArrayList);

        Double minLongitude = Collections.min(longitudeArrayList);
        Double maxLongitude = Collections.max(longitudeArrayList);

        points[0] = minLatitude;
        points[1] = minLongitude;
        points[2] = maxLatitude;
        points[3] = maxLongitude;
    }


}
```

Thanks in advance.

[image]

Comment: How can we help you by see this image? Please, post your code where you think can cause to memory leak

Comment: why do you want to reduce the memory usage? I assume you have some free space on your phone. (p.s. slovak!)

Comment: @Axarydax It should not consume too much memory..

Comment: but how do you know it is too much? If you show a MapView, it loads some tiles into a cache and has a lot of other stuff - maybe then 100 MB is appropriate.

Comment: How much memory does Google Map App use? Also, please share some code to show what you're doing.

Comment: @Simon Added Code in the question.

Comment: @MaximShoustin Added code in the question.